# More memory efficient algorithm for finding overlap in ranges

Tags: c++, algorithm, memory-management, stl

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33470036/given-a-set-of-ranges-s-and-an-overlapping-range-r-find-the-smallest-subset-in) question, the answer included an algorithm to find overlap of a list of ranges on a given range. But in my situation I have a list of `n` integers, which when grouped into `n^2` pairs form ranges. For example if we take `array[i]` and `array[j]` from the integer array, `(array[i]-array[j],array[i]+array[j])` make a range. But in order to implement the suggested algorithm, the solution is of `O(n^2)` memory complexity. Can it be optimized (in terms of memory) further?

Example:
I have a larger range `(l,r)`, and I have to find how many integers in `(l,r)` lie in at least any one of the list of ranges.For example, the given integer array is `{1,2,3}`. So all possible ranges are `(2-1,1+2), (3-1,1+3), (3-2,3+2)`. Suppose `(l,r)` is `(2,7)`. Then since `(2,5)` exist in at least one of them `4` is the answer.

Comment: @user3386109..... I have a larger range `(l,r)`, and I have to find how many integers in (l,r) lie in at least any one of the list of ranges. The list of ranges can be calculated from the given integer array in the way described in question.

Comment: @user3386109....for example the given integer array is `{1,2,3}`. So all possible ranges are `(2-1,1+2), (3-1,1+3), (3-2,3+2)`. Suppose `(l,r)` is `(2,7)`. Then since `(2,5)` exist in at least one of them `4` is the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by sorting the array (if it isn't already sorted). Then note that the only ranges worth considering are those where `j == i-1`.

To understand why consider the following array:

```
{2,3,5,8}
```

Then the possible ranges are:

```
i=3 j=2 ==> (8-5,8+5) = (3,13)
i=3 j=1 ==> (8-3,8+3) = (5,11)
i=3 j=0 ==> (8-2,8+2) = (6,10)

i=2 j=1 ==> (5-3,5+3) = (2,8)
i=2 j=0 ==> (5-2,5+2) = (3,7)

i=1 j=0 ==> (3-2,3+2) = (1,5)
```

Notice that the ranges for `j < i-1` are always strict subsets of the range where `j == i-1`, so those ranges don't need to be considered. So you only need to consider O(n) ranges.